# What might be the cause of lag of the OS in my computer?

Tags: linux, hardware-failure, lag

I have a laptop running Manjaro 15.12 that was working perfectly before I came back from my holidays. The computer is four years old but it has an (old) Intel i7 and 8GB of RAM.

Now it lags in a weird way. When doing something the system kind of freezes for a couple of seconds (any task like surfing the internet or writing a text file) from time to time but I can still move the cursor without any trouble. At first I thought that there might be some process using up too much resources but when I looked the output of *top* both the CPU and the memory were not being used. I also changed the HD drive a few months ago but I don't know if this information is helpful or not.

Why can this be?

EDIT: This is the output of smartctl (long run):

```
smartctl 6.4 2015-06-04 r4109 [x86_64-linux-4.1.15-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-15, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

The previous HD gave me errors when running smarctl and that was the  reason of changing it for a new one.

Comment: Sounds like a HDD health issue.  Run a tool that checks the S.M.A.R.T data and report back

Comment: If it was Windows I would suggest rebooting it 3 times in a row....

Comment: Just wipe and re-install - Get an SSD to replace to aging HDD. Job done!

Comment: @Ramhound I just added that data. smartctl doesn't report anything unusual.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I changed the HDD a few months back and smartctl doesn't find any problem in the HDD that's why I was wondering if the lag might be caused by anything else.

Comment: The only things I can suggest to do now are to check that your hdd BIOS setting for SATA is on AHCI not LEGACY or IDE. If ok check for bios updates and possibly change the ram?

Comment: reset bios to defaults as well, and then check the sata settings. if on ahci, boot then see if the lag disappears. Not having enough ram allocated to the video card can also cause lag.